# assigning a value to a variable in scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to assign a score on a scale to variable for which I have a counting function in Scheme. I want the function to return a score of 10 if the count is greater or equal to 2 and a score of -10 if the count is less than 2. This is the code I have:

```
(define theScore (lambda (x) 
  (cond ((if = x 2) (if > x 2) 10) (else( - 10)))))
```

It returns a 10 for everything, even the tests for which it should return a -10 as output. I can't figure out why, although I'm sure it's something obvious! Can you help me pinpoint what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most experienced Scheme programmers would write that function like this:

```
(define (the-score x)
  (if (< x 2) -10 10))
```

Here's a version that follows the style you used:

```
(define theScore
  (lambda (x)
    (cond ((>= x 2) 10)
          (else -1))))
```

Identifiers in Scheme are traditionally written with dashes separating words and do not use camelCase.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to see more of this kind of thing, you might enjoy my blog at http://programmingpraxis.com.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you perform a comparison in Scheme:

```
(if <condition>
    <something>
    <else>)
```

So basically it's a problem of syntax, that's all. In other words, this is how your procedure should look:

```
(define theScore
  (lambda (x)
    (if (>= x 2)
        10
        -10)))
```

Notice that comparing if a value is equal to or greater than `2` is performed by a single application of the `>=` operator, like this: `(>= x 2)`. Now, if you want to use `cond` (you were confusing this part), here's how it's done:

```
(define theScore
  (lambda (x)
    (cond ((>= x 2) 10)
          (else -10))))
```